# not all arguments converted during string formatting (while passing arguments to function)

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I am getting error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" while running this code please explain how to fix this and what is this error

```
def multiples(l,n):
    count=0
    for i in l:
        if(i%n==0):
            count+=1
    return count
m=input("no of elements: ")
l=[]
print("enter elements: ")
for i in range(int(m)):
    l.append(input())
n=int(input("enter no to find no.of multiples: "))
print(multiples(l,n))
```

error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
not all arguments converted during string formatting
  line 4, in multiples
    if(i%n==0):
  line 13, in <module>
    print(multiples(l,n))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `l` is the list of strings. Python `input()` stores the input as a string. There is no `%` (modulo) operation on the strings.

Comment: Hint: where the code says `n=int(input("enter no to find no.of multiples: "))`, what do you think is the purpose of the `int` part? Do you see why that might also be appropriate, when putting values into the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the list `l` that you are passing to `multiples` has strings inside instead of int which causes the code to call `%` on a string instead of modulo. You don't get a straightforward error as `%` acts a format string like `"% is my name" % name`. To fix it you can convert the `input()` to int as so: `l.append(int(input()))`

so your overall code would be

```
def multiples(l,n):
    count=0
    for i in l:
        if(i%n==0):
            count+=1
    return count
m=input("no of elements: ")
l=[]
print("enter elements: ")
for i in range(int(m)):
    l.append(int(input()))
n=int(input("enter no to find no.of multiples: "))
print(multiples(l,n))
```